# Limit number of objects in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an album which has_many photos.  A counter_cache setup updates the photos_count column in the album table.  How do I limit the number of photos for an album?

Comment: check the count before inserting?

Comment: probably not the most cute of all, but the most safe is @Marcel Jackwerth sulution, others with use of `validates_associated` allow you to create children without limit using `parent.children.create`

Answer (score 48):

In my case, it was sufficient to use `validates_length_of`:

```rb
class Album
  has_many :photos
  validates_length_of :photos, maximum: 10
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :album
  validates_associated :album
end
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution

Comment: Can confirm this works really well. Only problem is if you go the other way and just start creating a bunch of "Photos" that belong to album the same cannot be said. You will need to add :validate => true to the belongs_to, though I haven't tested to make sure this will always work as intended.

Comment: actually `belongs_to :album, validate: true` according to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to checks associations on the parent save, not on child save... so you can add as many children as you want, and this could be a problem

Comment: No need of validates_associated :album in Photo model. It will work without validates_associated as well.

Comment: I could create 11 photos using this code

Answer (score 29):

Use a validation hook:

```
class Album
  has_many :photos
  validate_on_create :photos_count_within_bounds

  private

  def photos_count_within_bounds
    return if photos.blank?
    errors.add("Too many photos") if photos.size > 10
  end
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :album
  validates_associated :album
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys.  I have got Marcel's code working.

Comment: photos.size is a better way to go - http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size, from a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836927/1396904

Comment: Amended as you suggested, @andorov

Comment: this solution still have a problem, you can add as many children, as you want with `album.photos.create`, at least with Rails 5.1.4, so it seems @Marcel Jackwerth sulution probably the best from this point of view

Comment: @max.underthesun Yes, because it only validates on creation of the parent model. You could validate always by removing `_on_create`.

Comment: @hurikhan77 I've checked it without `_on_create`, but with `parent.children.create` call from console I still can create one more `child` and exceed the limit by 1 (at least for my polymorphic association)... I suppose the problem here is with the `photos.size > 10` - on the moment of validation it is valid and became invalid just after the new `photo` creation... it could be only rails console issue though, I didn't check if it shows the same behavior then calling `create` from an application code

Comment: @max.underthesun Maybe try `photos.length`, and maybe change `has_many :photos, touch: true` so it updates the parent object and reruns the validations defined there. PS: The solution of @jstejada may be the better one with current Rails versions, it may still need `touch`.

Answer (score 9):

How about adding a custom validation method to the Photo model?

```
  LIMIT = 50

  validate_on_create do |record|
    record.validate_quota
  end

  def validate_quota
    return unless self.album
    if self.album.photos(:reload).count >= LIMIT
      errors.add(:base, :exceeded_quota)
    end
  end
```

Comment: thanks @Marcel Jackwerth! spend some time in `rails console` checking all 3 solutions, found out yours is the only which really preventing from creating "unwanted children" ))

Comment: This solution worked best for my similar scenario. Glad you included `.reload` in your solution. I initially omitted it, and found some (but not all) scenarios would use an outdated count, allowing excessive child records to be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('LOCK TABLE pictures IN EXCLUSIVE MODE')
  if (@album.pictures.count < 10) 
    @album.pictures.create()
  end
end
```

I believe this is the most correct solution. It guards against concurrency issues/race conditions.

Comment: I would add a `reload` in there to ensure ActiveRecord isn't giving you stale results. Something like `@album.pictures.reload.count < 10`