# Limit number of objects in has_many association with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mongoid

I want to limit the number of associated objects in a has_many association between a post and pictures :

In active record i can do something like

```
class post < < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :limit => 2
end
```

But mongoid raise an exception with limit:

> Invalid option :limit provided to relation :pictures. Valid options
>   are: as, autosave, dependent, foreign_key, order, class_name, extend,
>   inverse_class_name, inverse_of, name, relation, validate.
>   (Mongoid::Errors::InvalidOptions)

Is there an alternative implementation to relize :limit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit number of objects in has\_many association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263267/limit-number-of-objects-in-has-many-association)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `has_many :limit` doesn't actually restrict the number of objects in the association -- it just limits the number of results returned when querying the relation. You probably want something like this answer [Limit number of objects in has_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263267/limit-number-of-objects-in-has-many-association) -- which will show you how to check the number of assocated objects during validation.