# Carrierwave multiple file upload limited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, upload, carrierwave

For my application, users can upload 6 files in a form.
So I use this example for this, with "fields_for" : http://lucapette.com/rails/multiple-files-upload-with-carrierwave-and-nested_form/

Problem, it is infinite. Is it possible to disable the "Add" button after 6 times or is there any solution for it ? It is not a problem if the 6 fields are present but I don't know how to do this with Rails...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a class name to your file field tag. upon clicking the add new button check the class length in jquery an if it exceeds 6 disable the add button using jquery. As you need the validation in client side i think it will be easier to do. and make sure if used delete any file then enable the add button.

Answer (score 0):

[Limit amount of file uploads with carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238297/limit-amount-of-file-uploads-with-carrierwave)
May prove to be useful while limiting on Server side. On Client side, Sabyasachis answer may help you out.