# Restrict Number of Pictures Uploaded with Rails, Carrierwave/Rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick

A lot of info out there about how to limit image size in uploads with Carrierwave/Rmagick but I can't find anything that explains how to limit the number of pictures that a user can upload.

I have a standard set-up Carrierwave image uploader set-up in Rails and want to restrict the number amount of pictures allowed to be uploaded.  Can anyone provide any advice how any solutions on how to do this?

Have been looking for a week now without much luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the upload number of pictures by user , this answer here would be useful [Limit amount of file uploads with carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238297/limit-amount-of-file-uploads-with-carrierwave)