# Ruby on rails one to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `User` which has one to many relation to the `Image` model.

How can I limit user to be able to store only 3 images?

Comment: By adding a custom validator. Have a look at the guides, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: Some related answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263267/limit-number-of-objects-in-has-many-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about validation?

```
class Image
  belongs_to :user

  validate :max_3_per_user
  # (...)
  private

  def max_3_per_user
    if user_id && Image.where(user_id: user_id).count >= 3
      errors.add(:images, 'There can only be 3 per user')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Thanks for not providing explanation. I corrected my answer anyway.